# How to load an EDITABLE PowerPoint Personal VBA Macros file automatically?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

How can I load an editable copy of my personal PowerPoint VBA macros whenever I open PowerPoint? I'm looking for something similar to the Normal.dotm macro-enabled template file that Word uses. I want to open PowerPoint and start using my personal macros without regard to which presentation file that I open.

I know how to generate a "compiled" PPAM file from a PPTM macro-enabled file, but you can't easily edit a PPAM file without hacking the registry (DebugAddins=1). Is there an easy way to load the editable PPTM file when PowerPoint loads? I've spent a few hours on the net and trying various things, but without success. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save your macro file with the name **Blank.potm** to your templates folder. This sets it as the default presentation, so it automatically opens when you start PowerPoint.

As an alternative, you can also save the macro file as **Default Theme.potm** and place it in the **Document Themes** subfolder of your Templates folder. This is makes it display as *Default Theme* on the File>New tab of the Backstage.

Comment: Yes, I see how that works. The "Blank.potm" shows up in the New list as "Default Theme" and does not make me say Create. My own MyMacros.potm shows up in the same place but makes me click Create to create a presentation from it. I never would have thought of naming it Blank. Thank you!

Comment: What is the path this file should be in?

Comment: The default path for your Microsoft Templates folder in Windows is C:\Users\YourActualUserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates. On a Mac, its MacHD/Users/YourActualUserName/Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office/User Content/Templates. By default, both _App Data_ and _Library_ are hidden folders

Answer (score 1):

Another odd trick:

Put a shortcut to the PowerPoint EXE file on your desktop.

Right-click it, choose Properties and tack the full path to your personal macros file onto the end of the text in the Target: textbox.

OK the Properties dialog box and doubleclick the shortcut to test it. Now as long as you use that shortcut to start PPT, it'll open the macros file auto-macro-icly. ;-)

To find Microsoft's pre-made shortcut file to start with:

Click the Windows icon, lowerleft of your screen, type PowerPoint.

On the right side of the dialog that appears, click the down-arrow below the app's name and choose Open File Location. That opens a Windows explorer window on the folder with MS' PPT shortcut file.

Right-click and drag the file to your desktop and when asked, choose to COPY it there rather than move.

This is the one you want to add your macros file name to.